# How to re-run the ViewModel when you navigate between tabs in Oracle JET?

Tags: rest, router, oracle-jet

I am developing a CRUD app where i navigate from the page that display tables of my data to some forms to add or edit those data. i wanna, for example, when i add some data and navigate to the table page to show the new row added.

what i am using now is a refresh button that fetch again the data and insert it in the observable array.

here how i navigate to the tab when click submit:

```
   $.ajax({
            url: url +'/customer',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);

            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log("Something went wrong", error);
            }
        }).then(function () {
            oj.Router.rootInstance.go("customers");
            return true;

        })
```

and this is the refresh action that i use now:

```
  self.customerData = function (){
        tempArray = [];
        $.getJSON(url + "/customer").
        then(function(tasks){

            $.each(tasks, function (){

                tempArray.push({
                    customerId: this._id,
                    name: this.name,
                    address: this.address,
                    email: this.email,
                    phone: this.phone,
                    area: this.area,
                    empNum: this.empNum,
                    sector: this.sector,
                    website: this.website,
                    facebook: this.facebook,
                    linkedin: this.linkedin,
                    activity: this.activity.name,
                    country: this.country.name
                });
            });


            var auxTab =[];
            for (var i =0; i<tempArray.length; i++)
            {
                var obj ={};
                obj.customerId = i;
                obj.name = tempArray[i].name;
                obj.address = tempArray[i].address;
                obj.email= tempArray[i].email;
                obj.phone = tempArray[i].phone;
                obj.area = tempArray[i].area;
                obj.empNum = tempArray[i].empNum;
                obj.website = tempArray[i].website;
                obj.facebook = tempArray[i].facebook;
                obj.linkedin = tempArray[i].linkedin;
                obj.activity = tempArray[i].activity;
                obj.country = tempArray[i].country;

                if (tempArray[i].sector === 'true')
                {
                    obj.sector = 'Public';
                }
                else
                {
                    obj.sector = 'Private';
                }

                auxTab[i] = obj;


            }

            self.customerArray(auxTab);

        });
    };

  self.refreshClick = function(event){
        self.customerData();
        return true;
    }
```

i expect the row will be automatically shown when i navigate to the customer tab tab but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply call the `customerData()` method inside `connected()` function? This function is automatically invoked(if you have defined it) from the viewModel when a new html page is rendered.

Place this inside your ViewModel which has table data:

```
self.connected = function(){
    self.customerData();
};
```

For more details, see the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/jet/6/develop/using-oj-module-element.html#GUID-CDD14017-CCB1-48A0-84EC-5E20ED46B6E4).

Note: The `connected` function is used in version 6 and beyond. Before that the function was called `bindingsApplied`.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use ko observables to ensure that new data is reflected in the UI. In case you are navigating to a VM, while creating the VM, you would pass parameters to it, which can contain observables. In that case when observable is updated, no matter from where, will reflect in your VM.

I see that your method fetching customer data is a simple array and I assume that it is bound to the UI. Did you try making the tempArray as an observable array?